# Text file I/O works fine in VS2015 development but not IIS deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, publish, code-behind

The following code is c# from an aspx code-behind page.  The problem is with the final system.io.file line which works fine on my local computer when developing, but when I run it on my IIS instance hosted on a server I maintain.... the text I wish is not appended to the file by this command.  Thus far, I have made sure that the file has full read/write/create for the IIS user, network, local user, etc.  I have also tried changing the owner to be the IIS_USRS user.  No error is generated, though, I've never known how to debug the code-behind of a deployed site if it throws no error.

Thanks for any help.

```
namespace checkin
{
    public partial class buttonclicked : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var backendclickedprocindex = Request.QueryString["clickedprocindex"];
            string path = Server.MapPath(".");
            string pathfile = path + "\\clickedprocindex.txt";
            File.SetAttributes(path, FileAttributes.Normal);
            Label1.Text = pathfile;
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(pathfile, backendclickedprocindex + ",");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What server OS?

In Server 2016, find the app pool used by your website and check the "Identity" of that app pool. If it reads "ApplicationPoolIdentity", you need to add that specific App Pool Identity to your file share. Go to your folder, right click, properties. Go to Security, Edit. Add the user "IIS AppPool\YOURAPPPOOLNAME" and give it the rights it needs.

Comment: If it does not read ApplicationPoolIdentity but instead something like, "YOURDOMAIN\SERVICEACCOUNT", give that user the rights it needs to the folder.

Comment: I am running OS 2008R2.  The app pool is ApplicationPoolIdentity

Comment: Then, yes, you'll need to add the app pool to the file share as I described above. Note there is a space after IIS.

Comment: You bet. It's a big change from the old IUSR days.